# How can I pass the value of a list into a partial view using ViewBag?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, viewbag

I have a Index view showing all posts in my database. And I want to create a partial view that displays 5 most viewed posts.

Here is my PostController :

```
public class PostController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IUnitOfWork uow;

        public PostController(IUnitOfWork uow)
        {
            this.uow = uow;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var result = uow._post.GetAll().ToList();
            return View(result);
        }

        public IActionResult Details(int id)
        {
            var post = uow._post.Find(id);
            return View(post);
        }

        public IActionResult GetMostViewedPost()
        {
            var result = uow._post.GetMostViewedPost(5).ToList();
            return PartialView(result);
        }
    }
```

The Index.cshtml:

```
@using FA.JustBlog.Core.Models;
@model IList<Post>; 

<div class="row gx-4 g-lg-5 justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-md-9 mx-auto">
        <!-- Post preview-->
        @foreach(var item in Model)
        {
            <div class="post-preview">
                <a href="@Url.Action("Details", "Post", new {id = item.Id })">
                    <h2 class="post-title">@item.Title</h2>
                    <h3 class="post-subtitle">@item.ShortDescription</h3>
                </a>
                <p class="post-meta">
                    Posted by
                    <a href="@Url.Action("Details", "Post", new {id = item.Id })">JustBlog</a>
                    on @item.PostedOn
                </p>
            </div>
            <!-- Divider-->
            <hr class="my-4" />
        }
        <!-- Pager-->
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-end mb-4"><a class="btn btn-primary text-uppercase" href="#!">Older Posts →</a></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I complete the code for partial view with ViewBag? Help me out! Thanks!

Comment: what have you tried and where have you failed?

Comment: Have you tried the following: @{
        Html.RenderAction("GetMostViewedPost", "Post"); 
    }

Comment: Since you are using c# mvc  forget about viewbags,  otherwise you better  start to learn java or one of millions javascript-like languages

Answer (score 1):

This should get you close.

First, create the partial view file _MostViewedPosts.cshtml and add the following code:

```html
@model IList
<Post>;

  <div class="card">
    <h4 class="card-header">Most Viewed Posts</h4>
    <div class="card-body">
      <ul>
        @foreach (var item in Model) {
        <li>@item.Title</li>
        }
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Then, modify the Index action in your PostController to fetch the 5 most viewed posts and pass them to the partial view using the ViewBag:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var result = uow._post.GetAll().ToList();
    ViewBag.MostViewedPosts = uow._post.GetMostViewedPost(5).ToList();
    return View(result);
}
```

Finally, in your Index.cshtml file, add the partial view using Html.Partial() method:

```html
<div class="row gx-4 g-lg-5 justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <!-- Most Viewed Posts -->
        @Html.Partial("_MostViewedPosts", ViewBag.MostViewedPosts)
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9 mx-auto">
        <!-- Post preview-->
        @foreach(var item in Model)
        {
            <div class="post-preview">
                <a href="@Url.Action("Details", "Post", new {id = item.Id })">
                    <h2 class="post-title">@item.Title</h2>
                    <h3 class="post-subtitle">@item.ShortDescription</h3>
                </a>
                <p class="post-meta">
                    Posted by
                    <a href="@Url.Action("Details", "Post", new {id = item.Id })">JustBlog</a>
                    on @item.PostedOn
                </p>
            </div>
            <!-- Divider-->
            <hr class="my-4" />
        }
        <!-- Pager-->
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-end mb-4"><a class="btn btn-primary text-uppercase" href="#!">Older Posts →</a></div>
    </div>
</div>
```